# log in automatically in the inappbrowser

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

i create an app with ionic, angular and cordova. My app have 2 level (app level and inappbrowser level). The User switch between the level.
The user logs into the app once and when he switches to the inappbrowser, he should also be logged in here automatically. How can I implement this so that it remains automatically logged in at the inappbrowser level?
I have access to the webpage that I render as inappbrowser in my app.